# Eventbrite API Request Parameter

Tags: ajax, eventbrite

I want to get the list of popular events in San Francisco through
ajax request to Eventbrite API. Here's the code.

```
var city = 'San Francisco';
var query = "token=" + token + "&venue.city=" + city + "&popular=" + true + "&location.within=" + "10mi"
var $events = $("#events");

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?" + query,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers":{}
}
```

I'm getting results from other cities too. How can I set parameters to get results from San Francisco only? Also, I'm getting multiple copies of a single event. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Query is Incorrect for API v3**: When testing your query I received errors from the Eventbrite API. These errors are due to using the incorrect query parameters. For example 'popular' does not exist as a [parameter](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-search). Make sure to test your queries via their playground https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token='YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN'.

**SF Only Events:** There is no way to set parameters in the Eventbrite query for events only in SF unless you include a small search radius around the latitude and longitude. That method could possibly exclude some popular SF events. The best way is to query all SF area events and then manipulate the data you get back by filtering out events whose Venue city is not San Francisco.

**Popular Events:** To truly get popular events you'd need to know how many tickets have been sold for each event ([private data.](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/response_formats/event/#ebapi-id4)) Instead, we need to use the [sort_by parameter](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/#ebapi-get-events-search) in our initial query to get the 'best' events. Unfortunately, 'best' is very vague in the API but all we have to work with.

**Duplicate Events**: Given the below query you will not get duplicate events.

Try the below jQuery AJAX method:

```
const sfSettings = {
   url: 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/',
   data: {token: 'YOUR-OAUTH-TOKEN', sort_by: 'best',  'location.latitude': 37.7749, 'location.longitude': -122.4194, expand: 'venue'},
   crossDomain: true,
   method: 'GET'
}

$.ajax(sfSettings).done(function(eventObject){
   // All SF Area Events (Paginated by 50. Will only return first page.)
   const events = eventObject.events;
   // Create a new array of events whose venue is specifically in SF
   const sfEvents = events.filter(function(event){
     return event.venue.address.city === 'San Francisco';
   });
});
```